# Implement partition refinement algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, haskell, partitioning, pseudocode

## Partition Refinement Algorithm

I have this algorithm from another Stack Exchange question:

Let

```
S = {x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5}
```

be the state space and

```
R = {
      (x_1,a,x_2),
      (x_1,b,x_3),
      (x_2,a,x_2),
      (x_3,a,x_4),
      (x_3,b,x_5),
      (x_4,a,x_4), // loop
      (x_5,a,x_5), // loop (a-transition)
      (x_5,b,x_5)  // loop (b-transition)
}
```

be the transition relation

Then we start with the partition

```
Pi_1 = {{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5}}
```

where all the states are lumped together.

Now, `x_2` and `x_4` can both always do an `a`-transition to a state, but no `b`-transitions, whereas the remaining states can do both `a`- and `b`-transitions, so we split the state space as

```
Pi_2 = {{x_1,x_3,x_5},{x_2,x_4}}.
```

Next, `x_5` can do an `a`-transition into the class `{x_1,x_3,x_5}`,
but `x_1` and `x_3` can not, since their `a`-transitions go into the class `{x_2,x_4}`. Hence these should again be split, so we get

```
Pi_3 = {{x_1,x_3},{x_5},{x_2,x_4}}.
```

Now it should come as no surprise that `x_3` can do a `b`-transition into the class `{x_5}`, but `x_1` can not, so they must also be split, so we get

```
Pi_4 = {{x_1},{x_3},{x_5},{x_2,x_4}},
```

and if you do one more step, you will see that `Pi_4 = Pi_5`, so this is the result.

## Implementation

I do not know how to implement this algorithm in JavaScript.

```
// blocks in initial partition (only consist of 1 block)
const initialPartition = { block1: getStates() };

// new partition
const partition = {};

// loop through each block in the partition
Object.values(initialPartition).forEach(function (block) {

  // now split the block into subgroups based on the relations.
  // loop through each node in block to see to which nodes it has relations
  block.forEach(function (node) {

    // recursively get edges (and their targets) coming out of the node
    const successors = node.successors();

    // ...

  }

});
```

I guess I should create a function that for each node can say which transitions it can make. If I have such function, I can loop through each node in each block, find the transitions, and create a key using something like

```
const key = getTransitions(node).sort().join();
```

and use this key to group the nodes into subblocks, making it possible to do something like

```
// blocks in initial partition (only consist of 1 block)
const initialPartition = { block1: getStates() };

// new partition
const partition = {};

// keep running until terminating
while (true) {

  // loop through each block in the partition
  Object.values(initialPartition).forEach(function (block) {

    // now split the block into subgroups based on the relations.
    // loop through each node in block to see to which nodes it has relations
    block.forEach(function (node) {

      // get possible transitions
      const key = getTransitions(node).sort().join();

      // group by key
      partition[key].push(node);

    }

  });
```

}

but I need to remember which nodes were already separated into blocks, so the subblocks keep becoming smaller (i.e. if I have `{{x_1,x_3,x_5},{x_2,x_4}}`, I should remember that these blocks can only become smaller, and never 'interchange').

Can someone give an idea on how to implement the algorithm? Just in pseudocode or something, so I can implement how to get the nodes' successors, incomers, labels (e.g. a-transition or b-transition), etc. This is a [bisimulation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisimulation), and the algorithm is implemented in Haskell in the [slides here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/courses/lai0506/LAI11.pdf#page=34), but I do not understand Haskell.

Comment: Can you please link the other SO question?

Comment: Instead of using an object of arrays(?) for the partitions, try a `Map` that maps each state to the partition(-id) it currently belongs to.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2064525/94899